# wso2-is-5.11.0 callback url & authentication issue getting Could not handle request: /carbon/admin/login_action.jsp java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server

I couldn't run the /carbon, /myaccount, /console, URLs, Don't have idea to resolve this issue.

Error logs

[image]

URLs not running in the browser

[image]

Error logs after urls runs in browser

```
> [2022-01-05 14:07:09,398] [3a2961aa-a3e4-458f-b8b5-cff9837e420f] ERROR
> {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve} - Could not handle
> request: /carbon/admin/login_action.jsp java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:46)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 
> [2022-01-05 14:07:25,990] [dfce5468-835d-40f1-be1d-aa49c1fdf5c9] ERROR
> {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve} - Could not handle
> request: /myaccount java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:46)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 
> [2022-01-05 14:07:49,837] [40b419de-4a04-4f89-845a-c0905a0ed080] ERROR
> {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve} - Could not handle
> request: /console java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:46)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I got this issue too, it happened suddenly. Appreciate if you could share if there is any update.